# Google SpacesのGASで書き込んだアイコンを変更するには？

Tags: google-workspace

#### 要約

Google SpacesのGASで書き込んだアバター△を変更したのですが、変更できません。

１、で設定すると理解し設定してみましたが、△は変更できませんでした。
Googleに質問をしてみたとことでフォロー対象外ですが一般的な意見をいただけました。その内容は、【設定するメニュー遷移】を同じでした。その中で２の記載がありました。２だと問題なく１の設定で設定が可能でした。同じ画像でマイドライブURLに設定すると表示できませんでした。どのように設定したら変更は可能でしょうか。

#### 設定するメニュー遷移

１、Spaces＞アプリと統合＞Webhookを管理＞…（縦型）＞アバターのURL
【Google紹介URL】
２、Google紹介URL＝https://developers.google.com/chat/images/quickstart-app-avatar.png
【マイドライブURL】
３、マイドライブURL＝https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/.../quickstart-app-avatar.png